# w3 validation error with elementTransitions.js

Tags: jquery, html, css, validation, transition

I'm trying to use this transition plugin from http://dan-silver.github.io/ElementTransitions.js/ 
But it does not pass W3 validation process,it give me an error **Attribute et-in not allowed on element article at this point** and **Attribute et-out not allowed on element article at this point** is there any way to avoid this with jquery?

This is a code sample

```
<article class="et-wrapper et-rotate" **et-in="moveFromTop" et-out="fade"**>
                    <div class="et-page features-box">
                       <i class="fa fa-bookmark-o"></i> 
                       <h3>Click This Box</h3>
                       <p>Now that we know who you are, I know who I am. I'm not a mistake! It all makes sense! </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="et-page  features-box">
                       <p>Now that we know who you are, I know who I am. I'm not a mistake! It all makes sense! </p>
                       <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-green">View More</a></p>
                    </div>
                 </article>
```

To make it work need to have `et-in="moveFromTop"` `et-out="fade"` within article class.

Thank you!

Comment: you have to decide ... w3 standard or your standard .... :) you do not worry about so much ... but its only my opinion...

Answer (score 0):

I've done a slight rework in the script here. Change et-in and et-out to data-in and data-out, as html5 allows custom data- variables. And than change the elementTransitons.min.js function s(t, n) to work with data-in and data-out instead of et-in / out.